# How to append newline before every occurrence of time stamp in string property?

Tags: c#, regex, string, properties

I have a list containing string property's called `Actions`. Within each `Actions` string property there are multiple text entries separated by a timestamp like below:

```
05/10/2016 15:23:42- UTC--test
05/10/2016 16:07:04- UTC--test
05/10/2016 16:33:54- UTC--test
06/10/2016 08:24:52- UTC--test
```

What I'd like to do is insert a newline `\n` character before each timestamp in the string property.

So I looped through each record in the list, then tried to modify each string property by adding a newline to each timestamp. But I'm not sure how to get the timestamp value in the string to perform the replace:

```
//Not sure how to find the instance of timestamp in the string
foreach (var record in escList)
{  
    record.Actions = record.Actions.Replace("timestamp_text_string","\n" + "timestamp_text_value");
}
```

I was thinking of using a regex to match every string matching a timestamp pattern, but not sure if the regex works in this context:

```
string pattern = @"\[[0-9]:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}\]"; //timestamp pattern
record.Actions = record.Actions.Replace(pattern,"\n" + pattern);
```

How can you append a newline before every occurrence of time stamp in string property?

The desired result is that for every entry in the string property, i.e, `05/10/2016 15:23:42- UTC--test` there would be a new line added before that portion of the string. Giving the following output:

```
05/10/2016 15:23:42- UTC--test

05/10/2016 16:07:04- UTC--test

05/10/2016 16:33:54- UTC--test

06/10/2016 08:24:52- UTC--test
```

Comment: Can you show your desired result with an example?

Comment: @S.Akbari yes posted the desired result to the end of the question. My aim is to separate each timestamp + string entry with a line break so it will be more readable.

Comment: Does the entire list consist only of these strings that would match your regex? If so, it would be a lot easier to just insert a new line between each existing line, instead of using regex replacements.

Comment: The string property will contain a string with the above format, timestamp - text . The text and timestamp will vary on each consecutive entry in the string.

Comment: I guess you need to use RegEx to match the timestamp pattern and store in a variable and later replace that information with a new line + variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Split`:

```
List<string> result=new List<string>();
foreach (var record in escList)
{
    result.Add(record.Actions.Replace(record.Actions.Split(' ')[1], "\n" + record.Actions.Split(' ')[1]));
}
```

Comment: The property is contained within a typed list. So using the above and calling split tells me Models.Esc does not contain a definition for `Split`. Any idea how to resolve that?

Comment: @BrianJ Use `record.Actions.Split` instead. See updated answer.

Comment: ok makes sense to access the property value. Although this split call only splits the first timestamp entry and splits in the middle of the timestamp instead of the start. Any ideas?

Comment: @BrianJ Well you can change this based on your requirement. You can replace `[1]` with `[0]`.

Comment: @BrianJ Also please note: since you are in a `foreach` loop only one of your records affected because it overwrites in each iteration. Use another list of strings and add every affected record to it.

Comment: ok I see that setting index [0] will break at the start of the timestamp. This still only break the first line in the string. So all subsequent timestamp and string entries are not line broken. `30/09/2016 14:27:21- UTC--test
05/10/2016 13:35:50- UTC--test
05/10/2016 13:38:11- UTC--test``

Comment: I think it would be better to do something like this, `string timeStampPattern = @"\[[0-9]:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}\]";
                    esc.Actions = Regex.Replace(esc.Actions, timeStampPattern, "\n\0");`

Comment: @BrianJ As I said since you are in a foreach loop only one of your records affected because it overwrites in each iteration. Use another list of strings and add every affected record to it.

Comment: ok adding the List<string> and assigned individually didn't work in that case. But I noticed during debug that there was already line break \r\n in the string. So in order to give a double line break between each log entry I did the following: ` esc.Actions = esc.Actions.Replace("\r\n","\n\n\n");`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure If I understood your desired result correctly, but I think performance wise you would be interested in using a StringBuilder instead of a List. Here's a sample I made:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string action1 = "05/10/2016 15:23:42- UTC--test";
        string action2 = "05/10/2016 16:07:04- UTC--test";
        string action3 = "05/10/2016 16:33:54- UTC--test";
        string action4 = "06/10/2016 08:24:52- UTC--test";
        List<string> sample_actions = new List<string>() { action1, action2, action3, action4 };

        Record rec = new Record();

        foreach (string sample_action in sample_actions)
        {
            rec.Actions.AppendLine(sample_action).AppendLine();
        }
    }
}
class Record
{
    public StringBuilder Actions { get; set; }
    public Record()
    {
        Actions = new StringBuilder();
    }
}
```

Edited to match your needs

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `actions` has at least one element:

```
spacedAtions = actions.Take(1).Concat(actions.Skip(1).Select(a => $"\n{a}));
```